# Downloading MySQL data into CSV file using PHP returning whole web page

Tags: php, mysql, csv, download

My downloaded CSV file seems to contain the entire web page code, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Initially it was writing everything after the function call but by using exit() I was able to solve this problem.

```
        $filename = 'SalesReport-'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'.csv';
        // open raw memory in write mode as file so no temp files needed
        $fp = fopen('php://output', "w");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        //write in table headers
        foreach($row as $name => $value) {
            $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $seperator .= "\n";
        fputs($fp, $seperator);

        //skip past the 0th value
        mysqli_data_seek($sql,0);

        //write in the table data
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            $seperator = "";
            $comma = "";

            foreach($row as $name => $value) {
        //take any commas out initially which would confuse the csv file
                $value = str_replace(",", " ", $value);
                $seperator .= $comma.''.str_replace('','""',$value);
                $comma = ",";
            }
            $seperator .= "\n";
            fputs($fp, $seperator);
        }

        // tell the browser it's going to be a csv file
        header('Content-Type: application/csv;');
        // tell the browser to save it instead of displaying it
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'";');
        fclose($fp);
        exit();
```

Comment: what do you mean by the "whole web page" ?

Comment: If you have `<?php build_csv_file(); ?><html><body>Yo</body></html>`, then you're going to get "the whole page"...

Comment: It returns all the code I have written for the entire page. I only want the table to be in the downloaded file?

Comment: SOLVED: just needed to start with ob_clean();